# Navigation Bar Links Being Skewed

Tags: css, hyperlink, navigation, positioning, navbar

I'm a relative novice with coding but I'm building a Tumblr for a friend to look like a professional site.

The navigation bar is the only thing giving me trouble. I have it positioned properly and I've created an image map 5 different ways but every time, the links get skewed off to the left and I can't, for the life of me pinpoint the problem.

Here's the code for the mapping:

```
<div style="display:block; width:2819px; height:242px; background:url(http://25.media.tumblr.com/ebc94124ba5998d21de08ddcb2e49a2c/tumblr_mtyjp4OLQH1sw93yro1_1280.png); position:absolute; margin:0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
<map id="imgmap20139301813" name="imgmap20139301813"><area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="471,63,510,80" href="http://davidallanhowell.tumblr.com/homepage" target="_self" /><area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="541,63,590,79" href="http://davidallanhowell.tumblr.com/resume" target="_self" /><area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="622,63,662,79" href="http://davidallanhowell.tumblr.com/media" target="_self" /><area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="691,64,735,79" href="http://davidallanhowell.tumblr.com/studio" target="_self" /><area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="765,63,817,79" href="http://davidallanhowell.tumblr.com/contact" target="_self" /></map>
</style>
```

The second problem that didn't show up until I was trying to fix it, is now I have an unsightly grey bar running across the image as well.

[Here's the full site.](http://davidallanhowell.tumblr.com)

Help?

Thanks and apologies in advance for what is probably an obvious problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to say it, but your code is kind of a mess!

Why don't remove image map, and links from image and use html elements for that?

This code that i'm going to give you it's a good start for you to work on it!

```
<div style="display:block; width: 100%; height:242px; background:url(http://25.media.tumblr.com/ebc94124ba5998d21de08ddcb2e49a2c/tumblr_mtyjp4OLQH1sw93yro1_1280.png); position:absolute; margin:0px 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    <ul style="
    width: 361px;
    height: 17px;
    margin: 62px auto 0 auto;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
">
      <li style="
    float: left;
    margin: 0 15px;
">home</li>
      <li style="
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 15px;
">resume</li>
      <li style="
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 15px;
">media</li><li style="
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 15px;
">studio</li>
      <li style="
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 15px;
">contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Hope that helps, and any question just ask!

Comment: Thank you so much! Haha, yeah, I could tell it was a total mess. I've hacked a lot out. Still have a few bugs but nothing I can't figure out. ;D

Comment: OH! I actually do have one more question, sorry. The new bar looks great but it scrolls with the page now and there are bullets between links that I can seem to pinpoint in the script. Also, do you happen to know the script to keep it on top so the posts on the page scroll up underneath it?

Comment: Add position: fixed; top: 0; z-index: 100; to the div. and to remove the bullets add list-style: none; to the ul